# mysql catch all error handling

Tags: mysql

is there any way to capture all the errors the same way we can do with exceptions e.g. exceptions can be caught like

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        `@failurecode` = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, `@failuremsg` = MESSAGE_TEXT;
            SELECT 'FAILURE' AS RESULT, `@failurecode` AS RESULTCODE,     
            `@failuremsg` AS RESULTMESSAGE;
    END;
```

can all the errors be caught in one statement?

Comment: You can list several conditions after "FOR" (seperated by a comma), not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Solarflare, list of conditions can be specified but I need syntax to catch all errors instead of specifying each and every error code

Comment: `sqlexception` should already catch all literal errors (the problems starting with `error xxx: sqlstate: yyy errortext`). There are 2 more classes: `sqlwarning, not found`, which are not exactly errors, but can be catched too. That's it. Unless I misunderstood your problem, just list these 3 words after `for`. Otherwise, be more specific about what you are trying to do (e.g what "other errors" except the ones catched by `sqlexception` you mean)